# Keep 'Has Stopped Working' windows from popping up

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server, windows-error-reporting

I'm running a server and sometimes one of my apps will crash which shows this dialog

[image]

This is annoying because it holds the process open until someone physically jumps on the box and presses 'Close the program'.

What I'm wondering is how I can disable this damn dirty dialog box on my server?

Comment: Uhh... Maybe you should find out why the program is crashing rather than trying to disable the crash notification?? When your check engine light goes out, unplug the dash??

Comment: Check event logs for possible sources for the crash.  AS noted, the popup is there for a reason.

Comment: @HelpingHand The software is software I wrote.  I expect it to fail sometimes, I just can't handle it gracefully when this box pops up. A program should be allowed to crash without a dialog box of all things popping up(such a bad idea, especially on a server). Also, the comments aren't really constructive or relevant to the question: 'Joe Schmoes best practices' wasn't what I was looking for.

Comment: @techie007 The program fully stopping is part of my over all process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The registry way

<sup>*There's no way like the registry way.*</sup>

1. Open an elevated command prompt.
2. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /v "DontShowUI" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
   ```

### Additional information

There is also a related, per-user `DontShowUI` value stored in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting`. Machine settings takes precedence over user settings, and changes are applied immediately.

For testing purposes you can use [Bad Application](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/badapp.html):

> [This tool] **emulates a bad application**. BadApp allows you to change its process priority, start an endless loop (i.e. "hang" or stop responding) and crash its process.

---

## Using the Group Policy Editor

1. Start `gpedit.msc`.
2. Navigate to **Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Error Reporting**.
3. Double-click the **Prevent display of the user interface for critical errors** policy, and set it to **Enabled**.

> *At least Windows Vista.*
>
> This policy setting Prevents the display of the user interface for critical errors.
>
> If you enable this policy setting, Windows Error Reporting does not
>   display any GUI-based error messages or dialog boxes for critical
>   errors.
>
> If you disable or do not configure this policy setting, Windows Error
>   Reporting displays the user interface for critical errors.
>
> <sub>Source: [Group Policy Search](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#238)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a crashing program to test with on-hand, but give this a shot:

1. Run `gpedit.msc` to open the policy editor.
2. Navigate to `Computer Configuration > Policies  > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Error Reporting`
3. *Enable* the "Prevent display of the user interface for critical errors" policy.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Unfortunately I feel like I have to give it to the other dude, just because the quality of the answer. Thanks again for responding quickly.